# Hurtworld - Options for not freezing to death?

Tags: hurtworld

Just started playing Hurtworld since it was released on Steam. As a "hardcore survival" game, it's difficult to get started in a populated area due to lack of resources. You need wood and flint to make a campfire, and you don't have much time before night sets and you start to freeze to death.

Besides being inside a structure and making a campfire, are there any other ways to keep yourself warm? For example, you can run/sprint in DayZ and it will warm you up somewhat. That doesn't seem to be the case here though.

Comment: have you tried jumping in the fire? that should warm you up. still requires making one though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than standing near a campfire and staying inside, wearing warmer clothing will help, it should keep you warm for the whole night in most biomes except tundra